# How to fix arrow areas rendering in the wrong color in an slds-path?

Tags: slds

I'm writing a Lightning Component that renders an [SLDS Path](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/path/) based on some custom configuration data (so I can't use the [lightning:path](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_path.htm) component). A few weeks ago a colleague tried this out and couldn't get the arrow portion (pointed to by the feint red arrow in the image below) to render in the correct color.

I am now also stuck on this; the image below includes the markup being output at the moment. (I've been through various permutations starting from the sample HTML provided by the Lightning Design System site.)

What am I doing wrong?

In the SLDS CSS I see this that is probably relevant:

```
.slds-path__item:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: -1rem;
  width: calc(2rem - (2px * 2));
  height: calc(2rem - (2px * 2));
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  transform: scale3d(0.8, 1.1, 1) rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out, background-color 0.1s linear; }

.slds-path__item:first-child:before {
  display: none; }

.slds-path__item + .slds-is-complete:before,
.slds-path__item + .slds-is-current:before {
  background-color: #4bca81; }
```

[image: Path and markup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Basti's advice, this is what I ended up adding to the component to support arbitrary ordering of path items of these classes:

- slds-is-incomplete
- slds-is-complete
- slds-is-current

The CSS:

```
/* Incomplete followed by current: style the arrow before current grey (incomplete color) */
.THIS .slds-is-incomplete + .slds-is-current:before {
    background-color: #ecebea;
}
.THIS .slds-is-incomplete:hover + .slds-is-current:before {
    background-color: #dddbda;
}

/* Incomplete followed by complete: style the arrow before complete grey (incomplete color) */
.THIS .slds-is-incomplete + .slds-is-complete:before {
    background-color: #ecebea;
}
.THIS .slds-is-incomplete:hover + .slds-is-complete:before {
    background-color: #dddbda;
}

/* Complete followed by incomplete: style the arrow before incomplete green (complete color) */
.THIS .slds-is-complete + .slds-is-incomplete:before {
    background-color: #4bca81;
}
.THIS .slds-is-complete:hover + .slds-is-incomplete:before {
    background-color: #04844b;
}

/* Current followed by complete: style the arrow before complete blue (current color) */
.THIS .slds-is-current + .slds-is-complete:before {
    background-color: #0070d2;
}
.THIS .slds-is-current:hover + .slds-is-complete:before {
    background-color: #005fb2;
}
```

**PS**

This is now broken in Winter '19 - yet to investigate what has changed.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue a while ago and I was struggling with the same thing. Let me explain how I solved it. This is your selector:

```
.slds-path__item + .slds-is-complete:before,
```

What means as much as: Select `:before` of `is-complete` stages that come after a `path__item`.

What you need is the `:before` of the element that comes **after** the `is-complete`.

```
.THIS .slds-is-complete + li.slds-path__item:before {
    background-color: rgb(75, 202, 129);
}
```

This is what you need in case it gets hovered:

```
.THIS .slds-is-complete:hover + li.slds-path__item:before {
    background-color: rgb(4, 132, 75);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - though others might have hit this. So you found that you had to add your own CSS i.e. the "out of the box" CSS is incomplete?

Comment: Yes, I think so. At the end, we decided to define it for every case cause we had styling issues again and again in different scenarios.

Comment: I can get it to work as plain HTML but inside a component I can't. Will look a bit longer but may have to use your work-around...

Comment: Interesting, I'm curious about some new findings :)

Comment: Not having both "incomplete" and "current" helps. But I think there may be a built in assumption that "current" always precedes "complete" and so has the green triangle wired in. –

Comment: FYI Looks like something was fixed here in Winter '19. We had implemented below workaround and the component started to look weird after the sandbox update. I removed the workaround and it is looking fine again.

Answer (score 0):

based on all the comments and in a spring '19 org, I was able to fully customize the colors by (e.g. for current):

```
.THIS .slds-path__nav .slds-is-current {
    background-color: #04844b;
}
.THIS .slds-path__nav .slds-is-current::before {
    background-color: #04844b;
}
.THIS .slds-path__nav .slds-is-current::after {
    background-color: #04844b;
}
```